How to write stateful tests in python unittest?
I want to create a test suite for an existing library that is using unittest and is very hierarchical.
The Class hierarchy looks a bit like this:
A
|_B
|_C
  |_D
  |_E

Class A is created with an instance of B and C where C needs D and E. The instances are quite expensive to make so I want to reuse them for later testcases.
What I would want is something like this:
class TestsClass(TestCase): 
    def test_00_test_e():
        self.e = E()
        ...

    def test_01_test_d():
        self.d = D()
        ...

    def test_02_test_c():
        self.c = C(self.d, self.e)
        ...

    ...

This however is not possible since unittest creates an unique object for each testcase.
Is there a way to get this functionality within unittest so that I can work whithin the test framework of the project and don't have to add dependencies?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures?

I'd try to avoid that... you may get in situations where order of tests matters when one changes the state in these shared objects and another test assumes a different state.

Is it possible for you to use PyTest instead? It has Fixtures to support this behaviour across multiple tests.

@JBRWilkinson it would be possible, although not optimal, since the project already has a lot of test suites created with unittest and I would prefer to keep the project as spaghetti-free as possible

@Robert avoid what? setUpClass?

@iaquobe Avoid having tests that depend on each other. They  then become dependent of the order in which thy run, you cannot just run one of them, you may need to be careful where you can fit new tests in... in short, it makes for brittle tests, and when you don't trust your tests anymore, you are less inclined to run them or write new ones. Just my 2 cents.

@Robert I understand that it is usually bad practice, but I feel that there are some exceptions to this.
I am working on a machine learning library. If my test would be independent, then I would need to train a model for 20 minutes, test it and then I would need to do it all over again for each class that needs a trained model.
This could easily increase the time needed from ~30min to 2-3h. Not only this but I would still have to test each model, to make sure that it generates sensible output and that the failing tests are caused by the class and not by a poor underlying model.

You could have setUpClass() and call it before all the methods in the class are executed:
class TestsClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.e = E()  
        cls.d = D()  
        cls.c = C(cls.d, cls.e)  

    def test_00_test_e(self):
        # Use self.e instance


Thanks, this would be possible, although not perfect. With setUpClass I would have to create all of the objects upfront. Ideally I would want to first create e and d run their tests, and only then create c and test it. Would this be possible somehow?

It's not a good practice as reorder of the tests can break everything but you could do something like:
class TestsClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.e = E()
        self.d = D()

    def test_00_test_e(self):
        # use self.e

    def test_01_test_d(self):
        # use self.d

    def test_02_test_c(self):
        self.c = C(self.d, self.e)



I don't think this would work, since all test functions are run in a separate object so they don't have access to the same self.
But still thanks, I'll use @classmethod it should do the trick :)
